# Grey out entire windows screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a windows form application (C# visual studio).

- Is it possible to grey out the entire windows screen when a button is pressed?
- How can I work that out?
- Is it also possible to grey out the entire screen but leaving an ungreyed space in the middle for a message box for showing some text?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: When you say windows screen, do you mean the form or the desktop? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you just want a message box that must be clicked, which blocks any other interaction?

Comment: Like most people get on here and read the FAQ before posting...

But @Derek try putting the controls you want to "grey out" in a group box or other grouping control of your choice, and set the active property to false.

Comment: Sorry, meant enabled property, not active.

Answer (score 3):

Answers to your question:

- Is it possible to grey out the entire windows screen when a button is
  pressed?
  ***You can put a control like a panel over the entire window and hide it.
  In the button event you then make it visible.  Set the background of the panel to gray and vary the transparency to adjust it so until your window visibility beneath it looks right.
  This will force the window into a "modal mode" without any way out.  So you better have logic for undoing this as well.***
- How can I work that out?
  ***Make sure you have some event such as completion of an event or query to hide the control or the user will never get back into your application again.***
- Is it also possible to grey out the entire screen but leaving an
  ungreyed space in the middle for a message box for showing some text?
  ***That is more complex and to be honest with you I haven't played with WinForm is some time -- instead doing WPF for desktop.  You MAY be able to use clipping but you will have to do quite a bit of research into how to do it.  Use Google -- it can be your best friend.***

Comment: Should be able to accomplish the 3rd point simply through z-index stacking. Have your control to gray out the entire screen, but *above* that have another control to act as your white message box, centered horizontally and vertically.

Comment: I agree with Mike.  If you just need to display messages, and it is not a part of your hidden UI, then just plop that control inside the panel.  When the panel is hidden it should also hide the message box.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way:use XAML pop-up as described below

```
<Popup x:Name="pop" IsOpen="False" >

</Popup>
```

For more details visit below link. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/using-xaml-popup-in-wpf/

After this to blur the main grid on eventhandler for the event which shows the pop-up,set the opacity as shown in below C# code

```
if (pop.IsOpen == false)    
{    
pop.IsOpen = true;    
grdMain.Opacity = 0.4;    
}    
else    
{    
pop.isopen=false;    
}
```